# Java application to execute commands in command prompt

Tags: java, command

I would like to know, is there a way to let a java application open command prompt (cmd.exe) and type/execute commands, preferably without the user seeing the command prompt window.

If anyone knows a sample application or a piece of code that can do this, your answer will be appreciated!

Comment: Open a command prompt, not the way you want it. Execute commands, most defiantly. Check out [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The java.lang.ProcessBuilder and java.lang.Process classes are available for executing and communicating with external programs. With an instance of the java.lang.ProcessBuilder class, it can execute an external program and return an instance of a subclass of java.lang.Process. The class Process provides methods for performing input from the process, performing output to the process, waiting for the process to complete, checking the exit status of the process, and destroying (killing) the process.

```
public class ProcessBuildDemo { 
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

        String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "dir"};
        ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );
        //You can set up your work directory
        probuilder.directory(new File("c:\\xyzwsdemo"));

        Process process = probuilder.start();

        //Read out dir output
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n",
                Arrays.toString(command));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        //Wait to get exit value
        try {
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying it right now, you even thought of a working directory, very helpful :)

Comment: You code is working, but not exactly as I want, I would like to be able to run commands after

Comment: Why do we need to put "/C" as the second argument to cmd.exe?

Answer (score 3):

use below code to execute process using java.

```
final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();                
    commands.add("cmd");
    commands.add(input2); // second commandline argument 
    commands.add(input3);// third commandline agrument
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method. For example following code will execute the "ipconfig" command and print the result

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig"); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        String readline;
        while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(readline);
        }
```

Or according to MadProgrammer's comment you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ipconfig");
    Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        String readline;
        while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(readline);
        }
```

Comment: Make it use ProcessBuilder and earn yourself a up vote ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer .. added that too.. But what is the advantages of processbuilder over runtime.exec? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: ProcessBuilder is just that, it's a Builder. It simplerfies the process of generating a process, allowing you to pass a vararg of Strings for each parameter, instead of having to mess about with concaternating a String and allows you set a bunch of other properties really simply, it just makes a complex process easier

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you need to run inside the shell (cmd.exe) or just run a program that you would normally run from the shell.

If the former you need to invoke `cmd -c <string>` using the appropriate Java APIs.

If the latter you can use the Java APIs to invoke a process directly.

**IMPORTANT:** However there are many pitfalls with the Java Process APIs. You *can* use `java.lang.Process/ProcessBuilder` but see [this link](http://www.cnblogs.com/abnercai/archive/2012/12/27/2836008.html) to see the issues.

A better solution is to use [Apache Commons Exec library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) which solves all these problems for you.

Comment: I agree absolutely, [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) is another really good article on why not to use `Runtime` or `ProcessBuilder`. +1